# Data Annotation to validate confirm password

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

My User model has these data annotations to validate input fields:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
[StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 3 and 16 characters", MinimumLength = 3)]
public string Username { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required"]
[StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 50 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid email")]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required"]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password is required"]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

However, I'm having trouble working out how to make sure Confirm Password is the same as Password. As far as I know only these validation routines exist: `Required, StringLength, Range, RegularExpression`.

What can I do here? Thanks.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

If you are using `ASP.Net MVC 3`, you can use `System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute`.

If you are using `ASP.Net 4.5`, it's in the `System.Component.DataAnnotations`.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password is required")]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("Password")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

EDIT: For `MVC2` Use the below Logic, Use `PropertiesMustMatch` instead `Compare` attribute [Below code is copied from the default `MVCApplication` project template.]

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class PropertiesMustMatchAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' and '{1}' do not match.";
    private readonly object _typeId = new object();

    public PropertiesMustMatchAttribute(string originalProperty, string confirmProperty)
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {
        OriginalProperty = originalProperty;
        ConfirmProperty = confirmProperty;
    }

    public string ConfirmProperty { get; private set; }
    public string OriginalProperty { get; private set; }

    public override object TypeId
    {
        get
        {
            return _typeId;
        }
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString,
            OriginalProperty, ConfirmProperty);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
        object originalValue = properties.Find(OriginalProperty, true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
        object confirmValue = properties.Find(ConfirmProperty, true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
        return Object.Equals(originalValue, confirmValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that I'm using MVC2 so `Compare()` doesn't exist. Would I have to set up a custom validation routine?

Comment: Compare is not part of the MVC2 framework. So, I guess you have to write custom validation as routine.

Comment: Do you know that how can I set My error message in `[Compare("Password")]` like Required error message?

Comment: @MohamadMehdiHabibi, Use [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password did not match.")]

Comment: @Prasad Kanaparthi, I tried it. It doesn't work!
I use MVC5, VS2013 & EF6

Comment: @MohamadMehdiHabibi See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407067/implement-comparepassword-attribute-in-mvc  and  http://everythingworkflow.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/mvc-compare-compareattribute-fails-after-upgrading-mvc-to-net-4-5/

Comment: Consider using `[Compare(nameof(Password))]`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the compare annotation to compare two values, and if you need to make sure it isn't persisted anywhere downstream (For example if you are using EF) You can also add NotMapped to ignore any entity->DB mapping

For a full list of data annotations available, see here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("Password")]
[NotMapped]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: We have better to do it without magic strings: `[Compare(nameof(Password))]`

Answer (score 4):

Other data annotations are optional. You can add those according to your requirement but you need to do this to implement password comparison operation.

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("Password")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Blazor `EditForm` validation

The above answers didn't work for me as it was not displaying any message.

```cs
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class PropertyMustMatchAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' and '{1}' do not match.";

        public PropertyMustMatchAttribute(string originalProperty)
            : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
        {
            OriginalProperty = originalProperty;
        }
        
        public string OriginalProperty { get; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
            ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
            var originalProperty = properties.Find(OriginalProperty, false);
            var originalValue = originalProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
            var confirmProperty = properties.Find(validationContext.MemberName, false);
            var confirmValue = confirmProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
            if (originalValue == null)
            {
                if (confirmValue == null)
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }

                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage,
                    new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
            }

            if (originalValue.Equals(confirmValue))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage,
                new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one `[Compare("Password")]` works with .net6 and Blazor WASM for sure!