# implement [Compare("password")] attribute in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use the `Compare` attribute in MVC 4 to ensure user enters the same password twice during registration. I am using Code First approach. My sample model is as follows.

```
public class Registration
{
    public int RegistrationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [Remote("CheckUserName", "Home", ErrorMessage="Username is taken.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}
```

The only problem with this is that the database table that gets generated would contain two password fields. Is there a smart way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) (you mentioned code-first but didn't tag it), you can decorate the property with [`[NotMapped]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx) to tell the designer not to add the column.

However, it's a *better* idea to use separate models for the database and the view, then map the two for presentation or updating.

Answer (score 4):

The proper approach would be to use View Models instead of using your entity objects as View Models. You should never bind an entity model to a View. Just saying...

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public int RegistrationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [Remote("CheckUserName", "Home", ErrorMessage="Username is taken.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}

public class Registration
{
    public int RegistrationId { get; set; }        
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```