# How can I verify that two fields match using DataAnnotationsValidator in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am fairly new to development and attempting to learn C# development with Blazor. I am currently learning how to build forms using `EditForms` and validate using `DataAnnotationsValidator`.

I've successfully done most of what I need to do for validation before I move on to processing the form, however, I am having trouble with one important aspect of validation: The form I am working on is a registration form for a new user. Generally, when registering new users, you might wish to have a user re-enter a value like an email address or password to ensure that they have typed it correctly:

```
    <InputText @bind-Value=User.email id="email" /><br />
    <ValidationMessage For=@( () => User.email) />
    <label for="confirm">Confirm Email</label><br />
    <InputText @bind-Value=User.confirm id="confirm"/><br />
```

To validate these fields, I have class UserModel which I have instantiated as User().

```
@code
{
    UserModel User = new UserModel();

    class UserModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your email address.")]
        [Compare(email, ErrorMessage = "The email addresses you entered did not match.")]
        public string confirm { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string pwd { get; set; }

        public string error = "";

        public void Submit()
        {
        }
    }
```

In Microsoft's documentation for `DataAnnotationsValidator`, I found a Class `CompareAttribute`, which, according to the documentation "provides an attribute that compares two properties." I believe this will do what I need, but I am having trouble using it. `Compare` takes the argument `otherProperty` which I believe would be the other user input I am trying to match, however, I can't figure out how to pass the previous input as this argument.

I've tried `email,` however, an object reference is required. It doesn't seem like I'd want to reference an instance of the class within the class itself, so I tried `this.email` but got the error "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context."

If anyone could help me figure out the proper way to use the `Compare` class in my situation, I would be very appreciative. Otherwise, if I am barking up the wrong tree, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Dup? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237249/842935

Comment: @daniherrera The question you linked did answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: @daniherrera Not a duplicate. Linked answer predates Blazor by many years and doesn't work well with it. See my comment below answer.

Comment: Hi @Xeevis, I didn't vote to close, just asked. You have my re-open vote. By the way, can be a good idea to post your comment as an answer. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Blazor apps Microsoft created new NuGet package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation) for use with **DataAnnotationsValidator** component. This library defines attribute `[CompareProperty]` in the same namespace as former `[Compare]` attribute for which it's a direct replacement.

Working example:

```cs
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<EditForm Model="@_user" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <label>
        Email:
        <InputText @bind-Value="_user.Email" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Confirm:
        <InputText @bind-Value="_user.ConfirmEmail" />
    </label>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private User _user = new User();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }

    public class User
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [CompareProperty("Email")]
        public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can read more about why use of `[Compare]` attribute is not desired for the Blazor app [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-data-annotations-validation-package).

Comment: I got here from Google, so it's worth noting - it would be wise to use `nameof(Email)` as the argument to the `CompareProperty` constructor since it is more resistant to refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

My question was answered in this post stackoverflow.com/a/13237249/842935 (thanks Dani Herrera for pointing this out).

The argument is a string which represents the name of the property you are trying to compare to. Thus, the following code will do what I was trying to accomplish:

```
[Compare("email", ErrorMessage = "The email addresses you entered did not match.")]
```

Comment: Not a correct answer. CompareAttribute doesn't work well with DataAnnotationsValidator component because it doesn't associate the validation result with a specific member. This can result in inconsistent behavior between field-level validation and when the entire model is validated on a submit. In a Blazor app, it's better to use [CompareProperty] which is a direct replacement for the [Compare] attribute. It can be found in the experimental NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. If you post that as an answer with example usage I'll accept it. Either way, thanks for your help.